# I am trying to get text from an error message and compare to the expected but it returns "null" since don't have proper css path or html id

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am not entering any data in my form and trying to save it.
It should throw an error message. How to get the text of error message and compare in javascript 
I have written the following code but its taking null value.

```
var errorMsg=element(by.id('alert-div'));
    expect(errorMsg.getAttribute('value')).toBe('Please select the platform for the app');
```

it shows the following error message

> Message:   Expected null to be 'Please select the platform for the
>   app'. Stacktrace:   Error: Failed expectation

Comment: Can you post your html code? May be there is a problem with your element selection or you are expecting the value before the alert pops up. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

`.getAttribute` is async so you have to use it in async way.

```
var errorMsg = element(by.id('alert-div'));
    errorMsg.getAttribute('value'))
    .then(function (value) {
        expect(value).toBe('Please select the platform for the app');
     })
```

Comment: `expect()` by default resolves any promises passed to it before performing expectations in protractor.

Comment: @GirishSortur I think that depends what assertion library you are using.it is not always correct that expect() resolves the promise.

Comment: It does resolve every promise passed to it. [check the features of jasminewd2](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/tree/jasminewd2). If you go through the code then you will see that any instance of webdriver.promise passed to expect statement is resolved first.

Comment: How did you know Tanushree  has used `jasminewd2`?

Comment: code is `<div id="alert-div" class="" ng-show="error.type" style="margin-top: 65px; width: 1200px; margin-left: auto;">
<div class="alert ng-isolate-scope alert-error" ng-class="type && "alert-" + type" close="closeAlert($index)" type="error.type">
<button class="close" ng-click="close()" type="button" ng-show="closeable">×</button>
<div ng-transclude="">
<span class="ng-binding ng-scope">Please select the platform for the app</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: actually that error message alert box is not static it will come for some fraction of seconds and will hide.